# pandas dataframe in def

Tags: python, pandas, function

I tried the below code to pass a df to a def function.
the first line works fine with df.dropna.
however the df.replace has issue as I found that it does not do the replace as I expected.

```
def Max(df):       
    df.dropna(subset=df.columns[3:10], inplace=True) 
    print(df)
    df.replace(to_replace=65535, value=-10, inplace=True)
    print(df)
    
    return df
```

anyone know the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Without a sample of your data is hard to debug because your `replace` code works well. However, don't use `inplace` if you return `df`.

Comment: Consider changing the question name to a more descriptive one, there is nothing to do with `DataFrame` and `def`, it looks like just a `replace` issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well. Maybe try this version without inplace modifications:

```
>>> df
       A      B      C   D     E   F   G   H   I     J
0      1      2      3   4   5.0   6   7   8   9  10.0
1     11  65535     13  14  15.0  16  17  18  19  20.0
2     21     22     23  24  25.0  26  27  28  29   NaN
3  65535     32     33  34   NaN  36  37  38  39  40.0
4     41     42  65535  44  45.0  46  47  48  49  50.0
5     51     52     53  54  55.0  56  57  58  59  60.0
```

```
def Max(df):
    return df.dropna(subset=df.columns[3:10]).replace(65535, -10)
```

```
>>> Max(df)
    A   B   C   D     E   F   G   H   I     J
0   1   2   3   4   5.0   6   7   8   9  10.0
1  11 -10  13  14  15.0  16  17  18  19  20.0
4  41  42 -10  44  45.0  46  47  48  49  50.0
5  51  52  53  54  55.0  56  57  58  59  60.0
```